# find() first element from the jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've "cached" a jQuery object that I use inside a loop called `$myElement`. I would like to use some native JavaScript functions on it (for better performance). However, my attempts below throws errors (the element is undefined). Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
$myElement.find('span')[0];

$myElement.find('span').get(0);
```

Update: What Im trying to do is something like:

```
$myElement.find('span')[0].innerHTML('some text');
```

That's giving me an error.

Comment: What you typed is valid. We probably need more code to see your error.

Comment: Your syntax should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/mHUNU/

Comment: @dystroy Ok, please have a look at my update

Comment: Which element is inside the jQuery object `$myElement`? Is the `span` itself in there or a parent of it? If the `span` is already in the object you could also use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which doesn't read the DOM but only the objects contents.

Comment: @Johan You didn't posted any updates…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to need

```
$myElement.find('span')[0].innerHTML = 'some text';
```

Because innerHTML isn't a function on basic DOM elements.

But there is nothing wrong, if you get your element using jQuery, to also use the html function :

```
$myElement.find('span').first().html('some text');
```

I don't think you're optimizing at the right point.

Comment: or `$myElement.find('span')[0].html('some text')`if jQuerys abstraction is OK

Comment: no ... .html() can only be used on jQuery objects, but find('span')[0] isn't

Comment: @devnull69 He didnt say that. Neither is he using the `html()` method on the dom element

Comment: @Johan I think that devnull69 was speaking of the comment from mariusnn

Comment: but @mariusnn is ... my comment was referring to his/her comment

Answer (score 3):

The `.innerHTML` property is not a function. Just set its content using assignment.

```
.innerHTML = "foo";
```

But be careful with `.innerHTML` when using jQuery. If you clear content like that, and any of that content has any data or handlers assigned with jQuery, you'll have a memory leak.

A safer practice would be to use jQuery to update content.

```
.html("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[jQuery's "first"](http://api.jquery.com/first/)** function like this:

```
$myElement.find('span').first();
```

Or use to get an nth-child by an index using [**jQuery's "eq"**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) function, like this:

```
$myElement.find('span').eq(3);
```

Or you can also use **[jQuery's "get"](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** function to return a DOM instance of that match:

```
$myElement.find('span').get(2);
```

As you can see on this example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/be8YK/2/